# Oracle Turn Table on its side

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

Thank you for any help in advance as i can't seem to be able to figure it out.

I am running version 11 of Oracle DB. What I have is following table (PO_INFO_DATA):

```
PO_NUMBER  |  INFO_ID  |  INFO_DATA  |
```

Each PO_NUMBER can have up to 40 INFO_IDs assigned to it, from 1 to 40 and each INFO_ID will have a corresponding INFO_DATA.
So, for example,

```
PO_NUMBER | INFO_ID |  INFO_DATA    | 
-------------------------------------
500000    |     1   |      DRAMA    | 
500000    |     2   |      BELT     | 
500000    |     3   |      SPANDEX  | 
500001    |     1   |      34572    | 
500001    |     2   |      BONGO    | 
500001    |     3   |      POLYESTER|
```

and so on.

what I want to do is display it in this format:

```
PO_NUMBER | INFO_DATA_1 | INFO_DATA_2 | INFO_DATA_3 | ... and so on till INFO_DATA_40
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    PO_NUMBER, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 1, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_1, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 2, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_2, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 3, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_3, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 4, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_4, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 5, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_5, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 6, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_6, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 7, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_7, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 8, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_8, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 9, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_9, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 10, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_10, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 11, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_11, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 12, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_12, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 13, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_13, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 14, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_14, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 15, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_15, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 16, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_16, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 17, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_17, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 18, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_18, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 19, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_19, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 20, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_20, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 21, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_21, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 22, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_22, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 23, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_23, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 24, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_24, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 25, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_25, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 26, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_26, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 27, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_27, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 28, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_28, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 29, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_29, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 30, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_30, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 31, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_31, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 32, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_32, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 33, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_33, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 34, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_35, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 35, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_35, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 36, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_36, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 37, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_37, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 38, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_38, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 39, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_39, 
    DECODE (INFO_ID, 40, INFO_DATA) INFO_DATA_40 
    FROM 
        PO_INFO_DATA 
    ORDER BY PO_NUMBER ;
```

It sort of works, as it does put the table on the side but it creates multiple rows in the output as such:

```
PO_NUMBER | INFO_DATA_1 | INFO_DATA_2 | INFO_DATA_3.....
500000    | DRAMA       |             |
500000    |             | BELT        |
500000    |             |             | SPANDEX
500001    | 34572       |             |
500001    |             | BONGO       |
500001    |             |             | POLYESTER
```

I don't want to have multiple separate rows for this table. Each PO should just have one row. Please help me out rebuild my query correctly.

Comment: Ken, you are correct, i couldn't find it before even though i did look. Thank you so much, it's exactly what i needed!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for something like:

```
    SELECT   po_number,
             MAX (DECODE (info_id, 1, info_data, NULL)) INFO_DATA_1,
             MAX (DECODE (info_id, 2, info_data, NULL)) INFO_DATA_2,
             MAX (DECODE (info_id, 3, info_data, NULL)) INFO_DATA_3,
             ...
        FROM po_info_data
        group by po_number
        Order by po_number;
```

Just add for all you possible cases up to INFO_DATA_40.

Note that this solution is not flexible as it make assumptions you can have max 40 columns, meaning info_id column can have a max value of 40.

Comment: Vadimbo! Excellent, this works exactly as i needed. Thank you so much!